# Does Typeahead work inside a formTable?

Tags: xpages

I have a custom control that uses a formTable control that has a formColumn control inside it, 3 formRow controls inside the formColumn control and an editBox control in each of the formRow controls.  I'm trying to get Typeahead to work on the editBox controls.  These are for City, State and Zip Code and Typeahead is using a view called ZIPCodesByCity.  Column 1 contains the City, column 2 the State and column 3 the Zip.

Here is my formula for the Suggestions part of the City editBox:

```
@Unique(@DbColumn(@DbName()),"ZIPCodesByCity",1)
```

Minimum Characters in the Typeahead is set to 1 and Case-sensitve is unchecked.

When I preview the xpage, Typeahead does not work.

Any ideas?

MJ

Ok, I edited the code to be as follows and it still doesn't work.

```
@Unique(@DbColumn(@DbName(),"ZIPCodesByCity",1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I've done it too many times to count, I find that often with DbColumn and Dblookup it's easy to overlook the simple basics:

Have you looked at the ajax response from the typeahead in Firebug to see what is being returned?

Have you tested the DbColumn in a computedField to see what is returned?

Is it possible your DbColumn is exceeding 64k?

Are there any readers fields on the documents in the target view?

Comment: I think I'm reaching the 64K limit.  How can I get around that?

Comment: When doing typeaheads it's often better to use a DbLookup based on the value being keyed in by the user instead of a DbColumn:

- It helps to avoid the 64kb limit because you're refining the results
- You can return a smaller list of values in the typeahead box which is more user friendly

Keep in mind though that DbLookups can result in 64kb errors if you are looking up to a large list, which you probably are.  In that case, you might have the typeahead kick in after the user types 2 or more letters.

Comment: Here's a good example:  Here's a good example:  http://dominoextnd.blogspot.com/2009/02/xpages-how-to-make-type-ahead-work-for.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a type error in the formula: one of the brackets is positioned wrong. It should be:

```
@Unique(@DbColumn(@DbName(),"ZIPCodesByCity",1));
```

In your formula there was an extra ) after the @DbName() call.